# Java Fahrenheit=Celsius Program Issue

Tags: java

[EDIT] @Ryan Thanks for the solution! However, now I am receiving the error "c defined in first method" when I did not redefine it in the second.

```
public class cf {
public static void methodOne (double c, double f) {
    double c = 40;
    double f;
    System.out.println("Celsius Fahrenheit");
    while (c >= 30) {
        f = c * 9/5 +32;
        System.out.println((c) + "   "+Math.round(f*100.0)/100.0);
        c--;
    }
}
public static void methodTwo (double ce, double fa) {
    double ce;
    double fa = 120;
    System.out.println("Fahrenheit Celsius");
    while (fa >= 30) {
        ce = fa * 5/9 -32;
        System.out.println((fa) + "   "+Math.round(ce*100.0)/100.0);
        fa--;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Great.  What is your question?

Comment: "*I have the following output: ...*" than that is not the code you are using since it doesn't compile.

Comment: And please be  more careful when posting source code. Formatting is terrible. You want to us to read that; so you better spend the time to make reading easy.

Comment: Working fine on my machine. Getting this in output- `16.11111111111111|61.0
51.111111111111114|124.0`

Comment: *"c + "|" + f"* ... I wonder why you're using a `|` then you don't want it there.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `f += i * 1 + f;` and what do you think will happen each time you iterate? And if your boundaries are defined in celcius, why are you defining your while loop condition in Fahrenheit? And that while loop should be a for loop considering your objective.

Comment: i added a example that works as requested

Comment: Also note that 40 degrees celsius [is 104 fahrenheit](https://www.google.fi/?gws_rd=ssl#q=40+degrees+celsius), not 105.

Comment: You are trying to send a local variable c to your method cf when you already have a local variable names c the double you declared on line three. Also don't keep editting to ask more questions. accept a answer and then create a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your root problem is obviously that the conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit is implemented incorrectly within the loop. I would approach this problem by extracting the "beef" of your application, i.e. the temperature conversion (formula of which is [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit#Definition_and_conversions)), into a method of its own:

```
/**
 * Converts the input Celsius temperature into Fahrenheit degrees, using the
 * formula:
 * 
 * <pre>
 * (degreesCelsius * 1.8) + 32 = degreesFahrenheit
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @param degreesCelsius
 *            temperature in Celsius degrees
 * @return the temperature in Fahrenheit degrees
 */
private static float celsiusToFahrenheit(float degreesCelsius) {
    return (degreesCelsius * 1.8f) + 32.0f;
}
```

You should separate the calculation from the rest of the code because it:

- Improves the readability of your code
- *Separates the concerns* of iterating a range and calculating the conversion, which in turn makes

  - your application modular
  - implementing changes simpler
  - testing the conversion simpler
  - reusing the conversion possible

After you have done the above, the rest of the code only handles the initialization of the range and iterating over it:

```
// define the range
final int cMin = 30;
final int cMax = 40;

// run the conversion
for (int i = cMax; i >= cMin; i--) {
    float degreesCelsius = (float) i;
    float degreesFahrenheit = celsiusToFahrenheit(degreesCelsius);
    System.out.println(String.format("%.1f\t|\t%.1f", degreesCelsius,
            degreesFahrenheit));
}
```

Note that I've declared the Celsius degree range as `int`s because the requirement was an increment of one degree between each conversion. The values are *cast* into `float`s before the calculation.

You should avoid *magic numbers* in your code, which is why the range is defined as a pair of *final* variables (which you could also parse out from the `args` array, if you want to accept user input). The range could also be defined as `static final` fields if you don't expect it to change between runs of the program.

Finally, utility class [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) is used for outputting the data through `String.format()`. This makes it easy to change the precision of the `float` values in the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double c=40;
      double f;

    while(c >= 30){

        f = c * 9/5 +32;  //°C  x  9/5 + 32 = °F

        System.out.println(c + "|" + f);
        c--;
    }


}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This will format your code how you like it. It will give you your output as requested.

```
public class Far {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double c = 40;
        double f;
        System.out.println("Celsius Fahrenheit");

        while (c >= 30) {
            f = c * 9/5 +32;
            System.out.println((c) + "   "+Math.round(f*100.0)/100.0);
            c--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry to everyone for poor phrasing on what was the issue

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
        System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %-10s","Celsius ","Fahrenheit"));
        double f = 30;
        double c;
        double i = 1;
        while (f <= 120) {
            f += i * 1 + f;
            c = (5.0 / 9.0) * (f - 32);
        System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %-10s",(double) Math.round((c / c * 100) * 10) / 10,(double) Math.round((f / f * 100) * 10) / 10));
            i++;
        }
```